# How to use Udemy api using requests module in python

Tags: python, api, oauth, python-requests

I am trying to fetch some data from the udemy api. When I put a `GET` a request I get 403 status code

What I tried:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic {BASE64_ENCODED(CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET)}',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/', headers=headers)
```

I also tried using base64encode and using auth but that too didn't work.

According to Udemy,

> To send authenticated requests, provide the client_id and client_secret values as a base64 encoded HTTP Authorization header.
>
> > `curl --user {YOUR_CLIENT_ID}:{YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET} https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/`
> > `curl -H "Authorization: Basic {BASE64_ENCODED(CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET)}" https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/`

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: Did you try making sure your username/password are correct? Try this page: https://www.udemy.com/developers/affiliate/methods/get-courses-list/ and run it with your credentials. Note the extra information that goes into the headers.

Comment: Yes the client I'd and client secret is correct

Answer (score 0):

well, that's because you're sending a string that says:

```
"Basic {BASE64_ENCODED(CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET)}"
```

you're not passing actual base64 encoded parameters.
for starters import base64 then use it to encode YOUR client_id and YOUR client_secret, you should be able to figure out how to obtain those fron Udemy's API documentation, ultimately it should look something like this:

```
import requests
import base64

client_id = <client_id you obtain from Udemy>
client_secret = <client_secret you obtain from Udemy>

client_id_secret = f"{client_id}:{client_secret}"

b64_client_id_secret = base64.encode(client_id_secret)

headers = 
                  {
                    'Authorization': f'Basic {b64_client_id_secret}'
                  }
```

Comment: Using encode() I get a `TypeError: encode() missing 1 required positional argument 'output'`.